# Anchor the lone component in a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, resize, jframe, layout-manager

I have a single `JLabel` in my JFrame, initially displayed using `pack()`.

My problem is that whenever I try to resize the window, the `JLabel` also moves (depending on which side of the window is resized), largely due to the layout of the JFrame.

To be more specific, whenever I resize the window up/down, the `JLabel` stays centered. I would like that not be the case.

I'm sorry if my question is confusing. I'll gladly provide diagrams if requested.

```
public class JavaApplication8 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
        // TODO code application logic here

        JFrame window = new JFrame("test");

        URL bgURL = new URL("https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/3585146044/3b695fa73490227f792fa4e46d4a7a57.jpeg");
        ImageIcon bg = new ImageIcon(bgURL);

        JLabel label = new JLabel(bg);

        window.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        window.pack();
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setVisible(true);

    }   
}
```

Comment: Where do you want it to be? Also, it's not moved, it's enlarged (asuming you are using `BorderLayout`).

Comment: An [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) would be more useful than diagrams.

Comment: @brano88: I'm only displaying a single JLabel so I don't think the location is the question (in addition to the window set to `pack()`.

Comment: Then what you want to achieve?

Comment: @brano88: I've provided an SSCCE. Notice if u resize the window using the south border the whole image moves up a bit. What if I want to hide the lower part of her body (only using the south resize) but still see the face? I think I'm making this more complicated than it should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a different layout manager:

```
window.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
```

would be sufficient for the example.

Another possibility, if you want to keep using `BorderLayout`, is placing the label to a different position:

```
window.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

Also note that you should access swing components only from the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: I've actually used this but this removed the used to be function of the east resize border. Whenever I use the east border to resize the image moves the to the side a little bit.

Comment: @user2280704 I don't know what exactly you want, but `window.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING))` keeps the image at the top left corner.